# How to add an Image to ImageView dynamically from a JSON array

Tags: android, arrays, drawable, android-imageview

I want to add an image to my iamgeview from the link stored in a JSON file that looks like this:

```
{
"parts":[
    {"name": "Bosch Iridium",

        ...
        ...
        ...

        "image": "R.drawable-hdpi.plug_boschi"
    },
```

Right now I pull the link and display it with this code:

```
try {

    jObject = new JSONObject(sJSON.substring(sJSON.indexOf('{')));
    JSONArray pluginfo = jObject.getJSONArray("parts");
    JSONObject e = pluginfo.getJSONObject(position);

    String imagefile = e.getString("image");
    Drawable image = getDrawable(imagefile);

    ImageView itemImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.item_image);

    itemImage.setImageDrawable(image);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I'm pretty sure that this part is correct

```
ImageView itemImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.item_image);

itemImage.setImageDrawable(image);
```

But I need help with the part above that which is getting the link from the JSON array so I can display it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to get first the resource ID from the string contained in the JSON.

```
String imagefile = e.getString("image");
String resName = imagefile.split("\\.")[2]; // remove the 'R.drawable.' prefix
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(resName, "drawable", getPackageName());
Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(resId);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to look at the [Resources](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) class.

```
getIdentifier (String name, String defType, String defPackage);
```

So, basically parse the object to find the text `plug_boschi`, and call:

```
int resid=Context.getResources().getIdentifier ("plug_boschi", "drawable", null);
```